# Acessing a file mapping with a other function

Tags: c++, memory-mapped-files

Hello i have a process1 that correctly creates and mapped file(mmap for windows). I can correcty acces the mmap en write data in it, with the other process i can read the data.

There is a problem when i want to access the mapped file with a other function of process1.

I create the mapped file like this:

```
TCHAR szName[]=TEXT("Global\\MyFileMappingObject");

int mancontrol(void* pvBrick, HANDLE hMutex);

int main()
{
    //Handels and vars for IPC
    HANDLE hMapFile;
    LPCTSTR pBuf;
    char szMsg[256];
    string dataStr = "";

     //Create file mapping
     hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, BUF_SIZE, szName);
     if (hMapFile == NULL)
     {
        printf("Failed to create a mmap \n");

        return 1;
     }

    //Map file(MapViewOfFile) and return pointer of the mapped file(file view)
    pBuf = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, BUF_SIZE);
    if (pBuf == NULL)
    {
       printf("Failed to map mmap");
       CloseHandle(hMapFile);

      return 1;
   }
```

In the function that i want to acces the mapped file and write data to it looks like this:

```
int mancontrol(void* pvBrick, HANDLE hMutex, LPCSTR pBuf)
{
    char Msg[256];
    string dataString = "";
    dataString = "AAAA en BBBB";
    strcpy(Msg, dataString.c_str());
    CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, Msg,  strlen(Msg));
    dataString = "";
```

I don't get a new a error but the proces2 can't reads no data(in the main the data that i send there process2 can read). Do i need to open the mapped file in the function and map it again? Or is there something wrong with my argument passing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that bert-jan's guess is correct.

You can do a mapping to a real disk file, by passing a real file handle from CreateFile() as the first parameter to CreateFileMapping(), then the mapped file persists and its data will remain accessible.

You, on the other hand, have passed INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE as the first parameter, which creates a temporary memory file.  As soon as there are no mappings to the file, it will be erased.  When the second process creates a mapping, it gets a brand new file.

In real life, it is likely that the two processes will run for longer periods, so this may not be a problem.

Just for fun, I knocked up a quick sample program.  If the program is called fmap.exe (as my test version is) run one instance as "fmap server" and a second as just "fmap" (which is the client.

Type text into the client and it will be printed by the server.

```
// fmap.cpp 

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

// convenience class to manage a mutex
class CMutex
{
public:
    CMutex(const char *szName)
    {
        std::string sName = std::string("MUTEX_") + szName;
        m_hMutex = ::CreateMutex(
                        NULL,           //  __in_opt  LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpMutexAttributes,
                        FALSE,          //  __in      BOOL bInitialOwner,
                        sName.c_str()); //  __in_opt  LPCTSTR lpName
        if (!m_hMutex)
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create mutex");
    }
    ~CMutex()
    {
        if (m_hMutex)
            ::CloseHandle(m_hMutex);
    }
    void Lock()
    {
        ::WaitForSingleObject(m_hMutex, INFINITE);
    }
    void Unlock()
    {
        ::ReleaseMutex(m_hMutex);
    }

private:
    HANDLE m_hMutex;
};

// convenience class to lock a mutex and unlock it when it
// goes out of scope.
class CAutoLock
{
public:
    CAutoLock(CMutex &m)
    : m_mutex(m)
    {
        m_mutex.Lock();
    }
    ~CAutoLock()
    {
        m_mutex.Unlock();
    }
private:
    CMutex &m_mutex;
};

// Class to manage a mapped file
// uses the same name for the file and the mutex
class CMappedFile 
{
public:
    CMappedFile(const char *szName)
    : m_hMapFile(NULL)
    , m_szBuff(NULL)
    , m_mutex(szName)
    {
        m_hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
                            INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,  // HANDLE hFile,
                            NULL,                  // LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpFileMappingAttributes,
                            PAGE_READWRITE,        // DWORD flProtect,
                            0,                     // DWORD dwMaximumSizeHigh,
                            nBuffSize,             // DWORD dwMaximumSizeLow,
                            szName);               // LPCTSTR lpName 
        if (!m_hMapFile)
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create mapping");

        m_szBase = 
            reinterpret_cast<char *>(
                    MapViewOfFile(
                            m_hMapFile,           //  HANDLE hFileMappingObject,
                            FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,  //  DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
                            0,                    //  DWORD dwFileOffsetHigh,
                            0,                    //  DWORD dwFileOffsetLow,
                            nBuffSize));          //  DWORD dwNumberOfBytesToMap
        if (!m_szBase)
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create view");

        // reserve first few bytes of the file for a length variable.  
        // The rest is the buffer.
        m_szBuff = m_szBase + sizeof(size_t);
    }

    ~CMappedFile()
    {
        if (m_szBase)
        {
            UnmapViewOfFile(m_szBase);
        }
        if (m_hMapFile)
        {
            CloseHandle(m_hMapFile);
        }
    }

    // add a string to the mapped file
    void Put(const std::string &sVal)
    {
        // lock mutex
        CAutoLock l(m_mutex);

        // create reference to beginning of the buffer
        size_t &nLength = *reinterpret_cast<size_t *>(m_szBase);

        // check for overflow
        if (nLength + sVal.length() >= nBuffSize)
            throw std::runtime_error("Buffer Overflow");

        // copy string to buffer and increment length
        std::copy(sVal.begin(), sVal.end(), m_szBuff + nLength);
        nLength += sVal.length();
    }

    // read a string from the mapped file and
    // clear the length field, indicating that
    // this data has been read.
    std::string Get()
    {   
        // lock mutex
        CAutoLock l(m_mutex);

        // create reference to beginning of the buffer
        size_t &nLength = *reinterpret_cast<size_t *>(m_szBase);

        std::string sVal;
        if (nLength)
        {
            // if anything is in the buffer read ot
            sVal.assign(m_szBuff, nLength);

            // reset length as we've read the buffer
            nLength = 0;
        }
        return sVal;
    }

private:
    HANDLE m_hMapFile;
    char * m_szBase;
    char * m_szBuff;
    CMutex m_mutex;

    enum { 
        nBaseSize=1024,                     // whole file size
        nBuffSize=nBaseSize-sizeof(size_t)  // buffer size, after size has been reserved
    };
};

void DoClient(CMappedFile &m);
void DoServer(CMappedFile &m);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        const char szUniqueName[] = "CA249329_ACAE_11E0_9594_6CF0494804C2";
        CMappedFile m(szUniqueName);

        std::string sServer("server");
        if (argc==2 && sServer==argv[1])
            DoServer(m);
        else
            DoClient(m);
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

void DoClient(CMappedFile &m)
{
    std::cout << "Client running\n\n";
    std::string s;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, s))
        m.Put(s);
}

void DoServer(CMappedFile &m)
{
    std::cout << "Server running\n\n";
    while (1)
    {
        std::string s = m.Get();
        if (s.length())
            std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the process creating the memory mapping exits before the other process gets a chance to link to the mapping, in which case I would not be suprised if Windows deletes the mapping. How are things ordered in time in your application?

Comment: i had omitted the mutexes, the mutex makes sure the mmap is created and then released befor opening in the mancontrol function. to tomorrow i wil post the full code. I cant get to it now. Thanks for the feedback!